# Close full screen intent activity on notification click

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-fullscreen

I'm building a video calling app and need to display an incoming call screen. I use a Notification that displays an activity with fullscreen intent mechanism as follows:

```kotlin
private fun createIncomingCallNotification(): Notification {
    val fullscreenPendingIntent = IncomingCallActivity.intent() // from splitties.intents module
        .toPendingActivity(flags =
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        )
    return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_call_24)
        .setContentTitle("Incoming call")
        .setContentText("(919) 555-1234")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
        .setFullScreenIntent(fullscreenPendingIntent, true)
        .setContentIntent(
            VideoCallActivity.intent()
                .toPendingActivity(flags = 
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                )
        )
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setVibrate(DEFAULT_VIBRATE_PATTERN)
        .setSound(incomingCallSound)
        .build()
}
```

It is used as a notification for a foreground service which is triggered when the receiver receives an incoming call request.

The fullscreen activity and notification display OK. However, when I accept the call by clicking on the notification, fullscreen activity remains in the history stack (even with all these flags added plus the `autoCancel`). So then, when I end my call the fullscreen IncomingCallActivity pops up. It remains even when I stop the foreground service associated with the notification.

Any help would be appreciated!

**TL;DR:**

I'm looking for a auto-cancel-like behavior for a `fullScreenIntent` accompaniying an annotation. As it's for the system to decide whether the activity is shown, I'd like to have a generic approach to cancel the notification and close the fullscreen activity on any action selection (reject or accept the call). I suspect it should be done with a `BroadcastReceiver`, but looking for tips on how it ***should*** be done in a concise manner.

**EDIT:**

I've managed to solve this with `BroadcastReceiver` registered within the fullscreen activity with a `IntentFilter`. In the notification `reject` action I just `sendBroadcast` which then finishes the fullscreen activity.

However still looking for a 'best practices' approach on that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Strange that nobody answered yet.

Comment: I've managed to solve this with BroadcastReceiver registered within the fullscreen activity with a IntentFilter. In the notification reject action I just sendBroadcast which then finishes the fullscreen activity. But left it open hoping for a better solution

Comment: @JakubLicznerski For better clarity. can you please sample code of what you did?